# Clarification about UCCAPI in c#

Tags: uccapi

1. Using UCCAPI is it possible to identify through which client the message is comming for eg : if i am receiving thru Microsoft Office Communicator(MOC) or Custom Client
2. Say for Ex if 10 people are using the Custom Client if 3 are not signed in. but they signed in MOC is it possible to show they are in offline from custom client?.

Answer (score 0):

1 - In a custom application built using UCCAPI, it is possible to examine the incoming message before MOC gets to it, and decide whether to accept, ignore or reject the message. I believe you can pass some context through from the custom application that is sending the message, and this can be examined by the custom app receiving the message. That would tell you whether it was your custom client or the MOC client that sent the message.

2 - It might be possible to do this using [Custom Presence States](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963925%28office.12%29.aspx), although I haven't tried it.

Sorry I can't be more help - you might have more luck with this question on the [UCCAPI forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ucclientsdk/threads)